# Handling promise.reject to try-catch or promise.catch

Tags: node.js, promise, try-catch, sequelize.js

My understanding for promise is not perfect.
So I'm not sure which code is right way for handling error and exception cases.

Pleas help me to write code correctly.

1st.  try - catch for sequelizer's promise.reject

```
async function doGetAdminList(adminName) {

      let adminList;
      try {
        adminList = await sequelize.query(
          sqls.GET_ADMIN_LIST,
          { replacements: { adminName: adminName }, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
        );
      } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject({status:500, message: "SQL Error" });
      }    

      if (!adminList || !Object.keys(adminList).length) {
        log.info('\nadminList not found :\n');
        return Promise.reject({status:400, message: 'adminList not found.' })
      } 

      return adminList;
    }
```

For this, I wonder if try-catch can catch sequelizer's promise.catch().

2nd. do not handle sequelizer's promise.reject

```
async function doGetAdminList(adminName) {
          let adminList;
          adminList = await sequelize.query(
              sqls.GET_ADMIN_LIST,
              { replacements: { adminName: adminName }, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
          );

          if (!adminList || !Object.keys(adminList).length) {
            log.info('\nadminList not found :\n');
            return Promise.reject({status:400, message: 'adminList not found.' })
          } 

          return adminList;
        }
```

For this, I wonder if sequelizer's promise.reject() can be passed caller function and catched caller's at promise.catch().

Above sequelize-using function will be used below express function.

`adminController.js`

```
const jwtAuth = require('../common/jwtAuth.js');

exports.getAdminList = function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

  if (!req.body.adminName) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'adminName is empty.' });
  }

  jwtAuth(req.headers.accesstoken)
  .then((decoded) => {
    worker = decoded.loginName;
    return doGetAdminList(adminName);
  })
  .then((adminList) => {
    log.info("getAdminList() finish");
    res.status(200).json(adminList);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    log.error(e);
    return res.status(e.status).json(e);
  });
};
```

`jwtAuth.js`  is also promise function.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
module.exports = async function verifyJwt(token) {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!token) {
      reject({status:401, message:'Empty token'});
      return;
    }

    jwt.verify(token,"dipa",function(err, decoded){
      if(err) {
        reject({status:401, message:'TokenExpiredError'});
      } else {
        resolve(decoded);
      }
    });
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Inside an `async function`, just use `throw` instead of `return Promise.reject`

Comment: I think your question boils down to "*Should I not catch an error, or catch it and rethrow a different error*"? If `sequelize.query` doesn't reject with an object that has a `status`, the version that doesn't catch the sql error won't work.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, your're right.  I might totally misunderstand catch exception for reject.

Comment: @Bergi I'm still confusing try/catch can catch reject.  Is sequelizer's reject a also Error object?

Comment: Yes, if you `await` a promise that is/gets rejected then the error becomes an exception that can be caught using `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use 'async' if your function returns a promise, because `async` function returns a `Promise`.

What I mean is that the result of `var somethink = await doSomethink()` its not a promise its an object and because you return it from an `async` function its returned as `Promise.resolve(somethink )`.

So your 'jwtAuth.js' its better without

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
module.exports = function verifyJwt(token) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!token) {
      reject({status:401, message:'Empty token'});
      return;
    }

    jwt.verify(token,"dipa",function(err, decoded){
      if(err) {
        reject({status:401, message:'TokenExpiredError'});
      } else {
        resolve(decoded);
      }
    });
  }); 
}
```

Same goes for

```
function doGetAdminList(adminName) {

  let adminList;

  return sequelize.query(
    sqls.GET_ADMIN_LIST, {
      replacements: {
        adminName: adminName
      },
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    }
  ).catch((e)=> {
    //here you catch you sequelize error which can be anything
    //you can either catch and throw a new Error
    log.info('\nadminList not found :\n');
    throw Error({
      status: 500,
      message: "SQL Error"
    })
  })

}
```

About `getAdminList` and the `catch` at the end.

If `jwtAuth` or `doGetAdminList` throws an error `.catch` will receive the error.

If in `doGetAdminList` you dont do `.catch` on `sequelize.query` then the `sequelize error` will travel to your `catch` in here. But if you wanna handle the error and rethrow you error is possible.

```
const jwtAuth = require('../common/jwtAuth.js');

exports.getAdminList = function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

  if (!req.body.adminName) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'adminName is empty.' });
  }

  jwtAuth(req.headers.accesstoken)
  .then((decoded) => {
    worker = decoded.loginName;
    return doGetAdminList(adminName);
  })
  .then((adminList) => {
    log.info("getAdminList() finish");
    res.status(200).json(adminList);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    //the message with mess "SQL Error" will travel here.
    log.error(e);
    res.status(e.status).json(e);
  });
};
```

Adding, If you dont wanna change the error but you wanna log and passthroud the error you can rethrow it

```
.catch(function(e) {
    log.info('\nadminList not found :\n');
    throw e;
  })
```

Also if you wanna do `getAdminList` with `async/await`

```
exports.getAdminList = async function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

  if (!req.body.adminName)
    res.status(400).json({message: 'adminName is empty.'});

  try {

    let decoded = await jwtAuth(req.headers.accesstoken)
    worker = decoded.loginName;

    let adminList = await doGetAdminList(req.body.adminName);
    log.info("getAdminList() finish");

    res.status(200).json(adminList);

  } catch (e) {
     //the message with mess "SQL Error" will travel here.
    log.error(e);
    res.status(e.status).json(e);
  }

};
```

Comment: There's no good reason to use a `then` chain when you can also use `async`/`await`? Sure, in `verifyJwt` it's superfluous, but in `adminlist` it's quite beneficial.